# If device is infected, can new devices get malware from associated social media accounts?

Tags: malware, android, social-media

I have a couple social media accounts i want to use on a new phone ive got. The old phone i believe is infected with deep-malware. If I switch 2fa to my new phone which uses the same number but connected on a seperate network and change their passwords, could malware be transfered onto the new device? (Facebook, email, Discord, etc.)

Comment: Your question is too broad. Malware can transfer via many many vectors. So in theory yes, practically, who knows

Comment: @ISMSDEV There is believed malware on device A which contains social media accounts i want to use for device B. Given i want to still use them... as long as i set 2fa and a new password am i fine (im not using the same network aswell)

Comment: I think your question should be: is it possible to get infected? Not: can I avoid infection by doing these things.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the social media apps on the new phone from authoritative sources, I'm not sure how malware from another device could infect your new phone.

2FA would not help, because you would be logging into your accounts, and if there was some way to transfer the malware automatically, then it would happen after you used 2FA. Same thing for "changing passwords".

Using the same network will also not matter. Social media apps do not transfer data on the local network: they connect to servers on the Internet.

In short: malware does not work like that.

Comment: Also don’t “restore” your phone settings to the new device. You may transfer any “nasties” as well